# 404 errors in ESRI Leaflet when zooming too far with ESRI Basemaps

Tags: esri-leaflet

I was wondering if there was anyway to avoid 404 errors in ESRI Leaflet when zooming "too far" on the Satellite layer (`ArcGIS:Imagery`) with `L.esri.Vector.vectorBasemapLayer`.  I understand that the imagery tiles don't exist at deep zoom levels (in this case level 22) and the actual map displays as I would hope with a slightly blurry image. However, it is rather distracting to rack up potentially hundreds of 404 errors in the console.  Side by side comparison with the ESRI JS API show the same basemap display, the only difference being that the ESRI JS API returns no 404 errors. I am not sure if the JS API is just suppressing the errors or whether it is doing something more intelligent, but the results are nice. Note that this does not happen on the pure vector tile layers (example: `ArcGIS:DarkGray`) because there are no raster tiles to call.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`

[ESRI Leaflet example](https://codepen.io/natevatt-the-sasster/pen/ZEomVBr) - you can see from inspect tools that many 404 errors pop up

[ESRI JS API example](https://codepen.io/natevatt-the-sasster/pen/dyeQwRx) - the same location using the returns no errors

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to limit the zoom level to 21 where you have now `var map = L.map('map').setView([37, -122], 22);`?

Comment: @user30184 setting the zoom level to the limit of the tile layer will stop you zooming beyond that - I think punkfacenat wants to be able to zoom past the highest zoom resolution, accepting that this will result in blurry digital magnification and interpolation.

Comment: Could be, I thought they want just to prevent 404 errors. By reading the documents I noticed that setView sets the initial zoom level but does not limit anything. The option to add seems to be maxNativeZoom `If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels higher than maxNativeZoom will be loaded from maxNativeZoom level and auto-scaled.` https://leafletjs.com/reference.html

Comment: @user30184 Thanks for the tip.  As @Spacedman pointed out, my goal is to allow the user to zoom in as they wish, without getting the 404 errors.  I tried applying the `maxNativeZoom` option a number of different ways for this basemap, but was unable to change the results.